# Ubuntu server crashes while uploading large files

Tags: server, samba, raid, crash, upload

I'm trying to repurpose my old Dell Optiplex 745 as a media server. I loaded Ubuntu 16.04, set up drives in ext4 with snapRAID and SAMBA. I'm trying to upload movie and TV files from my newer PC running Windows 10.  The server crashes on upload of every 3rd to 8th file.

I get different messages. Some start with `BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000000000001`. Some with `general protection fault :0000 [#1] SMP`. Sometimes the server PC just spontaneously reboots.

The files are 1-5 GB in length and transfer very fast (approximately 100 MB/sec), when they work. I've tried it with the Windows firewall on and off. I've tried it with 8GB of memory and with 2 DIMMs removed to give 4GB. I've tried it with FTP using Filezilla in Windows, and by dragging and dropping with file manager. None of it makes any difference.  I have 3 dmesg log files from 3 crashes which can be provided if you can tell me how to attach them.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'd do a cap-check & inspection of hardware first.  I've discarded a 2x 745 & 1x 755 in the last 55 days because they'd failed. It's the *spontaneously reboots* that made me think hardware. Unless you've scripted a `reboot` somewhere, that shouldn't happen. If you suspect memory; that's easily validated using `memtest86`. I'd also monitor your 'heat' (I'm thinking stress on file transfer; heat/caps on way out, but 745 often had heat issues), but I'd suggest cap-check.

Comment: Thanks for your input guiverc.  You are correct.  The mainboard has 3 blown capacitors.  I'm surprised it worked at all.  I have a second old 745, a desktop.  The caps look OK.  I'll try running the server software on it.  If successful I'll move that mainboard into the tower case, taking advantage of the additional drive space and larger PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guiverc's comment is correct.  There were several blown capacitors on the board; readily visible with bulged tops and dried goo on them.  I swapped the motherboard from a 745 desktop (all caps good) into the tower and all of the above issues disappeared.